# R: how to make an error silent, still being able to use its dump

Tags: r

I'm randomising non-linear regression model within a loop. The `nls` (or `nlsLM`) function doesn't always converge, and breaks the loop with an error message. However, its last iteration parameters look satisfactory, and I can use it from the error dump.

```
dump.frames(dumpto = "last.dump", to.file = FALSE, include.GlobalEnv = FALSE)
thecoefs <- last.dump[["nlsModel(formula, mf, start, wts)"]]$getPars()
```

What I want is to make the error silent, so the loop goes on, still being able to get coefs from the dump. Perhaps the way is to use something like `try` or `tryCatchLog` functions, but when I use them, I cannot get the dump. The code above doesn't seem to work with them.

Please help me to make errors silent, still being able to use their dump.

Comment: Does it help adjusting the limit for convergence to the criteria achieves in the last cycle?

Comment: Thank you, mhovd! I will try your advice.